# How do I install PYQ in Conda or Pycharm?

Tags: kdb, pyq

I follow this link
[Install into a virtual environment](https://code.kx.com/q/interfaces/pyq/install/)

01 I create venv /home/evol/pyq

02 source /home/evol/pyq/bin/active

03 Download l64.zip to /home/evol/pyq/q

04 Copy license to /home/evol/pyq/q

05 The q folder is

[image: q folder]

06 Set activate file add code `echo "export QLIC=/home/evol/pyq/bin" >> ${pyq}/bin/activate`

07 `source ${pyq}/bin/activate`

08 `pip install pyq`

So i can`t install pyq

error
[image: error]

what`s problem ? how do i do ? thanks all

Comment: Your error image seems to cut off the most important part at the very bottom?

Comment: I expect there is more output for the error not included in that screenshot. If you include the full error message it would be easier to assist.

Comment: The manual page you link to carries a button Ask A Question. Did you try it?

Comment: Resolved @ https://community.kx.com/t5/Developer-Tools/I-can-t-start-KX-Developer-and-Pyq/td-p/13220